# Clarifications on proof of Hilbert's Theorem for finitely generated graded modules over $k[x_1,...,x_r]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

Here is Hilbert's theorem from Eisenbud:

> [image]

There are a few things I don't understand:

(1) Why does $H_M(s)=0$ for $s$ large in the case of graded vector spaces?

(2) What is the point of working with twists here? Is it used somehow that the maps between twisted objects have degree $0$ (map homogeneous elements to homogeneous elements of the same degree)?

(3) How does the equality (second display) follow from taking components of degree $s$? That is, why is the sum of dimensions of terms 1 and 3 equal the sum of dimensions of terms 2 and 4?

(4) I don't quite understand why $K$ and $M/x_rM$ are finitely generated modules over $k[x_1,\dots,x_{r-1}]$. Well, a f.g. module over a Noetherian ring is Noetherian, and $K$ is a submodule of a f.g. Noetherian module, so it's finitely generated. And the quotient of a Noetherian module is f.g. But why are they modules over $k[x_1,\dots,x_{r-1}]$?

Comment: (1) Can have a finitely dimensional graded vector space infinitely many non-zero graded pieces?

Comment: (2) Yes, the maps should be graded.

Comment: (3) An exact sequences of graded vector spaces splits in exact sequences of graded components which are also vector spaces. Can you show that the dimension behaves on exact sequences as they claim?

Comment: (4) If $M$ is a module and $I$ an ideal of $R$, then $M/IM$ is an $R/I$-module. Can you see that $x_rK=0$ and $x_r(M/x_rM)=0$?

Comment: @user26857 What do you mean by "graded maps"? Maps that preserve homogeneous degrees? Why should those maps be graded?

Comment: Yes, maps that preserve the degree. Do you know the definition of a morphism of graded modules?

Comment: @user26857 I see, so loosely speaking, since we are working with graded modules, all maps between them should be from the appropriate category.

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) A finite dimensional graded vector space has a finite basis. The degrees of these basis elements is a finite list of integers. Letting $B$ be the maximum degree, then $H_M(s) = 0$ for all $s > B$ since there are no elements of degree larger than $B$.

(2) Yes, that's right: a morphism of graded modules must preserve degrees, and that's what twisting accomplishes.

(3) This is just a statement about exact sequences of vector spaces, namely that they have Euler characteristic $0$. (See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2977715/).) This is really just a highbrow version of the rank-nullity theorem from linear algebra. Rank-nullity says that for a vector space $V$ with a subspace $W$, $\dim(V/W) = \dim(V) - \dim(W)$, i.e., $\dim(W) - \dim(V) + \dim(V/W) = 0$. We can express this as a short exact sequence of vector spaces $0 \to W \to V \to V/W \to 0$. One can generalize this result and show that given any exact sequence of vector spaces $0 \to V_1 \to V_2 \to \cdots \to V_n \to 0$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i \dim(V_i) = 0$.

Applying this to the exact sequence
$$
0 \to K(-1) \to M(-1) \to M \to M/x_r M \to 0
$$
we get
\begin{align*}
0 &= H_{K(-1)}(s) - H_{M(-1)}(s) + H_M(s) - H_{M/x_r M}(s) = H_{K}(s-1) - H_{M}(s-1) + H_M(s) - H_{M/x_r M}(s)
\end{align*}
and rearranging yields the result.

(4) We can consider any $k[x_1, \ldots, x_r]$-module as a $k[x_1, \ldots, x_{r-1}]$-module by considering the inclusion $k[x_1, \ldots, x_{r-1}] \hookrightarrow k[x_1, \ldots, x_r]$. The key observation here is that $x_r$ acts as $0$ on both $K$ and $M/x_r M$, so they are still finitely generated over the subring $k[x_1, \ldots, x_{r-1}]$.